# Can a number of the form $3n²+n+1$ have the sum of it's digits as $1999$?

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic

I observed that $3n²+n+1$ must be of the form $1 (\bmod9)$, as the sum of it's digits ($1999$) is $1 (\bmod9)$, what do I do now?

Comment: $3n^2+n+1\equiv 1\pmod 9\implies n\equiv 0\pmod 9$

Comment: $9^{229}$ does the job

Comment: $9^{213}+492156$ is the smallest I have found

Answer (score 1):

The short answer to your question is yes, a number of the form $3n^2+n+1$ can have a digit sum of $1999$.

For example, if
$$n=11967454043394296025270257234501220562460298994956800214778923296328286$$
$$593912561928317336796418458749456880763166308813694629126405260495377423753$$
$$928846460410045001564376789764786673412216704349942474013216490$$
then
$$3n^2+n+1=4296598688422634549180226287187215566468684970760664758940938659$$
$$552629810901202409193152723388562908239964708287192168615483358310836007727$$
$$971292085281048784075393371279683711247466269273603876363186364869614759614$$
$$576850048863907857107554940228661656982378108529385213002130211150065382807$$
$$397694014753196452498692479956477469375716779269297517185673547395956208720$$
$$10084967379804881991195022445182559599644060836976791$$

for which the digit sum is $1999$.

This was done with Python.  I assume the Python calculations are correct.  I have little reason to believe that this is the smallest $n$ that works.